# how to assign data dummy in a method with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Hello guys I have a question with rspec for rails, how I can assign data for a variable inside of my method for example `income_average = 12_00`0 without execute the code `researchable.whitelabel.applicants_income_average`

```
def benchmarks_alerts(researchable)
  income_average = researchable.whitelabel.applicants_income_average
  credit_averange = researchable.whitelabel.average_credit_requested
  errors = {}

  errors = errors.merge(income_in_the_mean: false) unless researchable.within_the_incomes_averenge?(income_average)
  errors = errors.merge(credit_in_the_mean: false) unless within_the_credit_averenge?(credit_averange)

  errors
end
```

Comment: `allow(:researchable).to receive(:whitelabel).and_return OpenStruct.new(applicants_income_average: 12_000)` should do it

Comment: I get this error  can't define singleton I'm doing some thing bad?

Comment: What is the class of researchable? Can you include the error trace in your question?

Comment: researchable is polyphormic class of user and just have this error TypeError:
       can't define singleton
     # ./spec/models/concerns/product_application_alerts_concern_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>' in the console

Comment: Thanks for you help I cant resolve this with before do
      allow(researchable).to receive(:whitelabel).
        and_return whitelabel
      allow(whitelabel).to receive(:average_credit_requested).
        and_return(12_000)
      allow(whitelabel).to receive(:applicants_income_average).
        and_return(12_000)
    end

Answer (score 0):

The following setup will mock the researchable object and its whitelabel method to return testable values for both `income_average` and `credit_average`.

HTH

```
describe Foo do
  subject(:foo) { described_class.new }

  describe '#benchmarks_alerts' do
    subject(:benchmarks_alerts) { foo.benchmarks_alerts(researchable) }

    let(:researchable) { instance_double('researchable', whitelabel: whitelabel) }
    let(:whitelabel) { instance_double('whitelabel') }
    let(:income_average) { 123 }
    let(:credit_average) { 456 }

    before do
      allow(whitelabel)
        .to receive(:applicants_income_average)
        .and_return(income_average)

      allow(whitelabel)
        .to receive(:average_credit_requested)
        .and_return(credit_average)
    end

    it 'does something' do
      # your test goes here
    end
  end
end
```